# How to transform a property of a class at runtime?

Tags: delphi, runtime, rtti

I have a class

```
type
  myClass = class
  private 
    FId: Integer;
  public
    function GetId: Integer;
    property Id: Integer read FId;
  end;
```

Now, I want to swap the `Id` property getter at runtime to use the `GetId` method instead of the `FId` field.  Can I use RTTI, or other methods, to realize this?

Comment: welcome to stack over flow please explain more it is unclear what are you asking.

Comment: property Id:integer read FId;
property Id value from Fid, I want swap GetId getValue in runtime

Comment: do you want to put the value of getid in Fid?

Comment: yes,but I must swap in runtime

Comment: you can try this "property Id:integer read GetId;"

Comment: no,I must change to this in Runtime,but not in edit

Comment: Why would you need to do it at runtime?

Comment: Run-time replacement code, I now do similar to the function of C # code first, which involves monitoring some of the properties, in the read, I want to dynamically replace the code, one or two, can not fully understand, but this is very urgent for me

Comment: I **think** what you want to do is modify the `read` getter of the `Id` property at runtime to call `GetId` instead of read from `FId`, is that right? If so, you can't do that replacement at runtime, let alone via RTTI. You can get info about the getter from RTTI, but you can't modify it. The compiled code for reading `FId` is very different then the compiled code for calling `GetId()`. Even if you could patch the getter in RTTI, that would only affect property access via RTTI. Normal property usage is hard-coded at each call site, so each call site would have to be patched individually.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note questions should only be posted after you have researched your issue, and include your attempts so far along with the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you, I think, really may not be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot replace property reader field with a getter method at runtime. But you can write this:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    FId: Integer;
    function GetId: Integer;
  public
    property Id: Integer read GetId;
  end;

implementation

function TMyClass.GetId: Integer;
begin
  if IWantToReturnField then
    Result := FId
  else
    Result := FId + SomeExtraStuff;
end;
```

Comment: Of course, I know that, but this one you wrote is not what I want, but thank you very much for your help

Comment: Perhaps there is more flexibility if that getter fires an event.

Comment: @David, depends on what you want to do. Firing an event is for class consumer.

Comment: I can't make sense of that comment. The user wants the flexibility to replace the entire body of the getter at runtime. Firing an event is the indirection that enables that.

Comment: @David, no, the OP wants either return field value or use getter method that is already implemented (_"I want to swap the Id property getter at runtime to use the GetId method instead of the FId field."_).

Comment: I should have read the question closely rather than your answer. You didn't implement what the user asked for. You need an extra function to be defined.

Comment: @David, because you cannot implement that. Yeah, maybe a replacable (inline) functions returning either the field value, or something else called from that getter may fit to this.

Comment: No. You need to add an extra function that acts as the getter. It either returns the field, or calls GetId. That's the extra level of indirection. An event would be another way to achieve that.

Comment: @David, well, but you end up with the same code as event handler, no? Or how else do you want to switch between which method should be called (if the one returning field value, or the other one doing some other stuff)?

Comment: I suppose so. Fair enough.

Comment: @Victoria:  I guess it is a matter of personal taste, but I would feel uncomfortable with the getter behaviour being dependent on `IWantToReturnField`, which is not overtly a member of TMyClass.  I would go the way David mentioned, with a getter event.  But ymmv of course.

Comment: @MartynA, it's an example, not a production code :) As for events, they're for class consumers rather than developers (for developers there are virtual methods). Of course, if the OP wants to let the class consumer define the getter behavior, then event is the correct way to go.

Comment: @mimakongjing You are sending inconsistent signals. In your comment you say *Of course, I know that, but this one you wrote is not what I want*. Then you still mark it as the best/correct answer! How come?